# Recursively deleting nodes from a balanced tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am working on a red-black tree and my insertion works fine, and my delete seems to work okay; however, if I run my program on thousands of entries, after a few hundred removals, the tree becomes invalid and the program then crashes. I have a `Node` class that handles insertion and deletion. I am using a recursive function to handle the fix after removal process. Eventually as my program removes nodes, it crash when calling this line here:

```
else if (isBlack(w->getLeft()) && isBlack(w->getRight())) { // handles case where siblings left and right children are black (or NULL)
    w->setColor(false); // red is false; black is true
    x = p;
    p = p->getParent();
    delProcess(root, x, p, z);
}
```

The error message is that `this` is a `nullptr` when calling it on `isBlack()`-- `this was 0xCCCCCCCC` to be exact. I have a validity checker that ensures each insertion and removal is valid, and I do noticed that prior to my program crashing with `this` being a `nullptr` the validity checks begin to consistently fail. Could someone take a look at my `delProcess()` method that handles fix up after removal? Does the recursive function look okay? I have been over it many times and I cannot seem to find the bug in my program. It seems as though the sibling (`w`) node ends up null at some point: https://pastebin.com/BsByvCfV

Comment: Not absolutely sure of it, but I think this better fits into StackExchange Code Review. But I`ll look into it anyway.

Comment: …aaand yes, it\`d be neat if you gave us the minimal buildable example and a testcase to see it crash.